# javascript array returns [object Window] instead of array content

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a problem. I wrote some PHP code that echoes `"var pixelArray = [];"`. after that it echoes a few variables like this: `"var canvas$id = 'can' + $id;"`. and also echoes `"pixelArray.push(canvas$id);"` for each variable.

Now for some reason when i run the script, the array doesn't contain anything.

Can anyone explain to me why?

If you need more information, please tell me.

EDIT:

Here's my full (but still simplyfied) code:

```
<?php
        $blockCounter = 1;
        $scriptCounter = 1;
        $arrayCounter = 1;
        $size = 32 * 32;
        $yLine = 1;
        while ($blockCounter <= $size)
        {

            if ($blockCounter == 32 * $yLine){
                echo "<canvas id=\"can$blockCounter\" width=\"17\" height=\"17\" style='border:1px solid #777777;'>GET A NEW BROWSER</canvas>";
                echo "<br>";
                $blockCounter = $blockCounter + 1;
                $yLine = $yLine + 1;
            }
            else{
                echo "<canvas id=\"can$blockCounter\" width=\"17\" height=\"17\" style='border:1px solid #777777;'>GET A NEW BROWSER</canvas>";
                $blockCounter = $blockCounter + 1;
            }

        }
        echo "<script>";
        echo "var pixelArray = [];";
        while ($arrayCounter <= $size)
        {
            echo "var name$arrayCounter = 'can' + $arrayCounter;";
            echo "pixelArray.push(name$arrayCounter);";
            $arrayCounter = $arrayCounter + 1;
        }
        while ($scriptCounter <= $size)
        {
            echo "var c = document.getElementById(\"can$scriptCounter\");";
            echo "picoco$scriptCounter = c.style.backgroundColor = \"#000000\";";
            $scriptCounter = $scriptCounter + 1;
        }
        echo "document.getElementById(\"arrayLoc\").innerHTML = pixelArray[0];";
        echo "</script>";
    ?> 
    <p id="arrayLoc"></p>
```

Comment: If you can, put all the code, so we can read it better.

Comment: Yeah, sure i can do that, but it's a very large piece of code. I'm going to make a simplified version, okay?

Comment: @EVDE_KSP alright ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementById("arrayLoc") is returning null, not the pixelArray[0]. The problem is that the paragraph tag has not been loaded into the DOM at the time of the javascript load. You can put it above the script shown below.

```
    echo '<p id="arrayLoc"></p>';
    echo "<script>"
    echo "var pixelArray = [];";
    while ($arrayCounter <= $size)
    {
        echo "var name$arrayCounter = 'can' + $arrayCounter;";
        echo "pixelArray.push(name$arrayCounter);";
        $arrayCounter = $arrayCounter + 1;
    }
    while ($scriptCounter <= $size)
    {
        echo "var c = document.getElementById(\"can$scriptCounter\");";
        echo "picoco$scriptCounter = c.style.backgroundColor = \"#000000\";";
        $scriptCounter = $scriptCounter + 1;
    }
    echo "document.getElementById(\"arrayLoc\").innerHTML = pixelArray[0];";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Or run the javascript after the DOM has loaded.

```
    echo "<script>";
    echo "window.onload = function () {";
    echo "var pixelArray = [];";
    while ($arrayCounter <= $size)
    {
        echo "var name$arrayCounter = 'can' + $arrayCounter;";
        echo "pixelArray.push(name$arrayCounter);";
        $arrayCounter = $arrayCounter + 1;
    }
    while ($scriptCounter <= $size)
    {
        echo "var c = document.getElementById(\"can$scriptCounter\");";
        echo "picoco$scriptCounter = c.style.backgroundColor = \"#000000\";";
        $scriptCounter = $scriptCounter + 1;
    }
    echo "document.getElementById(\"arrayLoc\").innerHTML = pixelArray[0];";
    echo "}";
    echo "</script>";
?> 
<p id="arrayLoc"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help first of all. But that doesn't seem to be the problem, here's a screenshot of inspect element, the values do get passed to javascript, it's the pixelArray.push(name) that doesn't seem to work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cbtswtk4vycb52/Schermafdruk%202015-09-17%2019.32.26.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah, your document.getElementById("arrayLoc") is returning null. Not the array.

Comment: put <p id="arrayLoc"></p> above the <script> tag

Comment: So the problem is basically that Javascript was looking for an element with an id while it wasen't loaded yet? I tried it, and it worked! thanks man!!! sorry for my pretty incomplete information.